# ftpclient downloaded file corrupted in android

Tags: android, ftp-client

Hi When I am trying to download a file from FTP Server in android ,The file is getting download but it is corrupted.
I have attached my code for download.

```
    {FileOutputStream br = new FileOutputStream(DestPath);
              mFTPClient
              .setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile(srcFilePath,br);
```

}

Can anyone tell me what is the issue.

Comment: Any chance you can give an Android/ftpClient version number? Also, is the file the correct size after download or is it missing bytes?

Answer (score 3):

You're not using the write method. `setFileTransferMode` is for transfer modes. `setFileType` is for setting file types.

```
.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

See the docs for [setFileType](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileType%28int%29) and [setFileTransferMode](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileTransferMode%28int%29).